# Nhibernate should have only one work query inside session or multiple query?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I am very confusing about design pattern with Nhibernate and worried about performance, scalability.

should we put one query inside Nhibernate session or multiple query both select and insert inside session.

I now using session per request in ASP.NET MVC, this design make the one session associate with select, insert,update delete.

I would be grad if you can give me some add vice or unit or work session.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only one query in each session would completely negate all features and meanings of a session. Take change tracking for example: NHibernate needs to flush the same session that loaded/inserted the entity to know what changed.

Using session per request is perfectly fine and most likely the most common pattern when using NHibernate in ASP.NET.